# Servlet handling multiple post requests

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets

I have one Servlet name EditEvent and one JSP which contains two forms. 
One for adding new event, The other one is for removing an event.

Is it considered as good practice to be using two separate servlets to handle one JSP?
If not, how would you handle two post requests from one servlet? i.e The Add event and remove event request.

cheers

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For handling multiple requests by same servlet you have to make a contract to have a request parameter like 'ACTION'. Then in your forms add this as hidden field with values like 'ADD' and 'REMOVE'. So, in doPost() you can check this parameter value and can invoke respective handling methods in same servlet.

```
class YourServlet extends HttpServlet{

      public void doPost(HttpReq req, HttpResp resp){
               String action = reg.getParameter('ACTION');
               if('ADD'.equals(action)){
                   addEvent();
               }
               if('REMOVE'.equals(action)){
                   removeEvent()
               } else {
                   defaultAction();
               }
      }

}
```

Comment: Clever idea of using hidden field.

Comment: The hidden field is unnecessary. Just use the name of the pressed button. I thought it was obvious/trivial, but apparently not, so I edited my answer with an example of the HTML.

Answer (score 11):

It's all your choice. It depends all on the current and future functional requirements. A simple alternative is to just introduce one or two `if` blocks in the servlet wherein you check which button is been pressed:

```
if (request.getParameter("add") != null) {
    // Perform add.
}
else if (request.getParameter("remove") != null) {
    // Perform remove.
}
```

assuming that the buttons look like this:

```
<input type="submit" name="add" value="Add" />
<input type="submit" name="remove" value="Remove" />
```

A complex alternative is to step over to a normal MVC framework where you just have to specify specific action methods. For example, [JSF](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info):

```
<h:commandButton value="Add" action="#{bean.add}" />
<h:commandButton value="Remove" action="#{bean.remove}" />
```